# Ruby true, false, or nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object with a boolean var.

```
 field :processing, :type => Boolean
```

The dev before me wrote some code that says this.

```
 :processing => nil
```

(He is, for some reason, setting it to nil instead of false.)

He then does this if statement

```
 return if self.processing
 dosomethingelse....
```

If I write code that does this

```
:processing => false
```

what happens the next time this code runs? Does dosomethingelse run?

```
return if self.processing
dosomethingelse....
```

UPDATE ===========

To many questions below so will answer here.

I added this

```
  field :processing, :type => Boolean, :default => false
```

and it broke the app. When I changed to the above dosomethingelse never gets run?
    `return if self.processing` returns. Any suggestions?

UPDATE 2 =======================================

Here is every reference to processing in my code (redacted). Also I am using MongoDB if that matters.

```
.where(:processing => nil).gt(:retries => 0).asc(:send_time).all.entries


if self.processing 
end


return if self.processing
self.update_attributes(:processing => true)
dosomethingelse....


.where(:sent_time => nil).where(:processing => nil).gt(:retries => 0).asc(:send_time).all.entries

:processing => nil
```

Comment: in this case `false` and `nil` should behave the same. so yes, `dosomethingelse` should run if `:processing => false`

Comment: `false` and `nil` function in a similar way in conditions. They only differ with the intent (for the human side). When you want to oppose `true`, you use `false`. When you want to express the lack of a value, you use `nil`.

Comment: As long as you do not check with `self.processing == false` it should work the same way.

Comment: After your **EDIT** it seems to me that maybe that the `field` command is doing something other than what it _seems_ to be doing. Could you post a more complete example? Your code explicitly sets the type to Boolean, so it might e.g. be that `field` defines a Boolean with a default value of `true`. Without a more complete example it's just guessing.

Answer (score 9):

Ruby uses `truthy` and `falsey`.

`false` and `nil` are `falsey`, everything else is `truthy`.

```
if true
  puts "true is truthy, duh!"
else
  puts "true is falsey, wtf!"
end
```

Output is `"true is truthy, duh!"`

```
if nil
  puts "nil is truthy"
else
  puts "nil is falsey"
end
```

Output is `"nil is falsey"`

```
if 0
  puts "0 is truthy"
else
  puts "0 is falsey"
end
```

Output is `"0 is truthy"`

See this explanation [True and False](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362#whats-truthy-and-falsey-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

You could use double negating to "cast" an object to a boolean value:

```
!!nil # false
!!false # false
!!true # true
```

In general, only `nil` and `false` gives `false` as result. So, in `if` statements `nil` and `false` are interchangeable.

Comment: there shouldn't be a need for that. `if self.processing` should evaluate to false if `self.processing` is `nil` or `false`

Comment: I haven't meant to use double negating in the app's code, I've just recommended way to check their behaviour

Comment: How does double negating help understand whether they are interchangable? How is your argumentation different from saying: "I have `1` and `2`, and I multiply both with `0`, respectively. Now, both became `0`. Hence `1` and `2` are the same"?

Comment: As for me, double negating is convenient way to do smth like casting object to a boolean. By the way, `1` and `2` are interchangeable in certain example of multiplying with zero. But you are right at that point that my explanation isn't very clear.

Comment: See my edit above as my code breaks when I set processing to false by default.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `dosomethingelse` gets run.

In ruby (almost nearly absolutely) everything is an object and every object is either "truthy" or "falsey". In general, everything is "truthy" except for the two constants, `nil` and `false`.  This means that the code `if foo != nil` can be written more succinctly as `if foo`. You are branching based on the "nilness" of a particular value - similar to how you might more explicitly check for `foo == null` in more traditional languages.

A pattern where this shows up a lot is with ruby Hashes. By default a hash returns `nil` if a key is missing. So you might have code that works like this:

```
def foo(opts = {}) # Optional named arguments
  # If :bar is not found, than => nil, so the first part of the conditional
  # evalutates to false and we return the result of the second expression
  bar = opts[:bar] || default_bar
end
```

There is an important caveat though! `false` and `nil` are not the same. Both semantically and in practice. Sometimes you actually want a boolean and then you need to be sure that you are checking explicitly for either that boolean or for `nil` (depending on what you are testing).

```
def display(opts = {})
  # This will always result in fullscreen = true!
  fullscreen = opts[:fullscreen] || true
end
```

Comment: `NIL` and `FALSE` are constants, whereas `nil` and `false` are literals (or keywords).

Comment: BTW, you cannot distinguish between a missing key and `nil` (or the hash's default value) when using `Hash#[]`. Therefore, you should use [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) which takes an optional default value, e.g. `opts.fetch(:fullscreen, true)`

Comment: See my edit above as my code breaks when I set processing to false by default.

Comment: @Stefan surely it makes sense to refer to `true`, `false` and `nil` as constants, even if ruby also defines `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `NIL`?

Comment: @Stefan Using `Hash#fetch` is good practice, but it means that the user supplies the default value. That's different behavior from having the Hash specify it (which needn't necessarily be `nil`).

Comment: Would you refer to `1` as a constant?